# fprintf not printing on the file

Tags: c, glib

I'm trying to print the contents of a slist from GLib into a file but when I run my code the file ends with the "1" that I print in the beginning and nothing more.

```
void fprint(gpointer key, gpointer value, gpointer data){
    FILE* op = fopen ("Output.txt", "w");
    fprintf(op, "1 ")
    g_slist_foreach((GSList *)value, (GFunc)fprintf, NULL);
    fprintf(op,"\n");
    fclose (op);
}
```

I also tried to use `g_fprintf` insead of the regular `fprintf` but it ended in this error

`(process:31431): GLib-CRITICAL **: 19:15:51.707: g_vfprintf: assertion 'format != NULL' failed`

The regular `printf` works fine without any problem

Comment: `fprintf` is not of type `GFunc`, so what kind of miracle are you expecting here? Just write a wrapper function that conforms to `GFunc` and does what you want it to do.

Comment: since printf worked fine I expected fprintf to be the same

Comment: Well, if you put `(GFunc)` before it just to silence the compiler, you are asking for it.

Comment: @Loki How do you expect `g_slist_foreach()` to know that it should pass `op` as the first argument when it calls `fprintf()`? You never passed that variable to it.

Comment: Where is the `fprintf()` format string? I don't see how this could work with `printf` either.

Comment: @Barmar AFAICT: This "works" with `printf` IIF each data member (a `void *`) of the `GSList` is actually a string, as that would be the first argument passed to `printf`. The third element of `g_slist_foreach` becomes an excess second argument to each `printf` call. This is UB territory, and would surely explode if the strings contain a specifier. The assertion we see is because `fprintf` is being called with the same order of arguments, a `void *` for the first argument, where a `FILE *` is expected, and `NULL` for the second argument, where a format string is expected.